# MVC 3 - Binding to a customised anonymous type linq query

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

Following example works. No questions about that. Question is how to make following example work with a **anonymous type result set of a complex query formed of select new {...}**

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var myJobs = from j in db.Jobs where j.deleted == false select j;
    //Need to REPLACE myJobs WITH a complex query
    return View(myJobs.ToList());
}
```

Index View:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProj.Models.Jobs> //NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Jobs";
}
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        Job-No
    </th>
    <th>
        Job-Name
    </th>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@String.Format("{0:000000}", item.jobId)
            </td>
            <td>@item.jobName
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried sending as model : "@model List<MyProj.Models.Jobs>" ?

Comment: I need to bind anonymous type not MyProj.Models.Jobs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to understand your problem from the question - 'I don't know what to do' is a bit vague.

However, this is my guess to your problem:

If the elemental result (i.e. `IEnumerable` of ***element***) of that query is an anonymous type due to a `select new {}`, then I suggest making a known type which mirrors the results you expect (all the way through, incidentally - i.e. nested enumerables etc) and replace the anonymous projection with that type instead.  Now you can use that type declaratively in the view.

i.e. if your query is like this

```
from job in jobs
where !job.deleted
select new { id = job.id }
```

Make yourself a model type:

```
public class JobQueryResult{
  public int id { get; set; }
}
```

And change your `select` accordingly:

```
select new JobQueryResult { id = job.id }
```

Then you can also make a constructor on the model type, which simply takes a `Job` object, and have that pull in the data you need (taking the responsibility away from the query expression).

Either way, you now you have an `IEnumerable<JobQueryResult>` which you can easily use as a Model type in your view.

A quick and dirty would be to consider using `dynamic` instead - (but you didn't hear that from me).

Comment: I think you understand the question. Comment 'Not sure what to do' is because that is where the question starts. I see some light in your answer but could you please give me an example. I am new to mvc tbh. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the fact that you want to get "select new " shown ... you still need to send something to the view. Take the entity with the most fields that are present in your new entity.

Create a partial class

```
namespace YourDomain.Model
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(EntityWithinXList))]
    public partial class EntityWithinXList
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string DesiredFieldFromA{ get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int DesiredFieldFromB{ get; set; }
    }
    public class EntityWithinXList
    { }
```

So you need to add 2 new fields from 2 other tables to your entity:

```
 var list = (from x in xList 
             join a in AList on x.commonfield equals a.commonfield
             join b in BList on x.newCommonField equals b.newCommonField
                            select new { x, a.DesiredFieldFromA, b.DesiredFieldFromB }).ToList();

list.ForEach(el =>
                {
                    el.x.DesiredFieldFromA= el.DesiredFieldFromA;
                    el.x.DesiredFieldFromB= el.DesiredFieldFromB ;
                });
return list.Select(p=>p.x);
```

Unless I've misunderstood your question this should do it . And the list that you are sending to the view is `List<EntityWithinXList>`